# Why does my javascript calendar widget not work in IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have a contact form with a calendar widget that pops up when the user clicks in a specifically classed input field. It works in IE8, Chrome, Firefox, but not in IE7. However, it doesn't throw up any errors, so I don't know where to begin debugging.

Site: http://www.exclusivevillas.co.za/contact-us/

Other (possibly relevant) information:

- Site runs on WordPress
- Contact Form is generated by Contact Form 7 plugin
- Valid XHTML Valid CSS3 (but ignore the ugly styling in IE 8 -- that's another query in DocType: doctype.com/wont-table-style-nicely-ie)

Comment: hmm... sounds like a DOM issue... perhaps related to event listener registration?

Comment: Hi Amanda, welcome to SO. I see you have some styling issues with the calendar as well? I'm testing in Chrome. Are you seeing this as well? How are you testing the site?

Comment: @drachernstern - yes, having styling issues in IE, but I think I'm getting the CSS working now - styles fine in Chrome though (at least on my machine?)

Comment: Hi Amanda, did you final got a solution for javascript issues from contact form 7 on ie 7?

I'm also experiencing the same issue but I can't tell what's wrong with the css code or php, it works in ie9 & ie 8 and also in chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a fix yet but if not, check out a recent post I wrote which outlines how to resolve the issue for ie.[Link to post on ie Contact form 7 calendar bug](http://norfolktechnology.com/2011/04/contact-form-7-calendar-ie-bug/)

Hope this assists, let me know if it works for your issue.

Cheers

Ric

Comment: Providing information about the solution rather than just a link will improve the helpfulness of your answer.